# Xcode thinks control may reach end of non-void function due to returns in if/else statements

Tags: objective-c, if-statement, return

This is a simple question: why does the following code cause a "Control may reach end of-non-void function" warning? Under what circumstances would one of the two return statements not be hit? Would it be more standard coding practise to place the second `return` statement outside of the `else` block? This does silence the warning, but I'm curious as to why it exists at all.

```
- (CGFloat) tableView: (UITableView *) tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *) indexPath
{
    NSString *lineToFit = [[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath: indexPath] line];
    NSString *actorToFit = [[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath: indexPath] actor];
    CGSize lineSize = [lineToFit sizeWithFont: [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize: 12.0f] constrainedToSize: CGSizeMake(320, 800)];
    CGSize actorSize = [actorToFit sizeWithFont: [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize: 12.0f] constrainedToSize: CGSizeMake(320, 800)];

    if (shouldDisplayExtra) {
        kExtraCellType cellType = [self cellIsGoingToContainExtraView];
        if (cellType != kExtraCellTypeNone) {
            [cellsToContainExtra setValue: [NSNumber numberWithInt: cellType] forKey: lineIDString];
            return lineSize.height + actorSize.height + 200;
        }
    } else {
        // Return the line height, actor height, plus a buffer.
        return lineSize.height + actorSize.height;
    }
}
```

Comment: The code looks fishy anyway: `kExtraCellType` looks like a constant, not a type. `[self cellIsGoingToContainExtraView]` looks like it returns a BOOL, not a `kExtraCellType`. How shall it calculate anything meaningful without parameters identifying the cell? You should recap Cocoa coding style conventions.

Comment: See my answer maybe it helps http://stackoverflow.com/a/39275095/1470374

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You do have a condition that results in no return:

if `shouldDisplayExtra` exist and `cellType == kExtraCellTypeNone` then there is no return defined...

You should add an else block to the conditional:

```
    if (cellType != kExtraCellTypeNone) {
        [cellsToContainExtra setValue: [NSNumber numberWithInt: cellType] forKey: lineIDString];
        return lineSize.height + actorSize.height + 200;
    } else {
       // return something here
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Friends its so simple,
If we declare function of int type and in which into The if,for..etc statement we return an value then it shows this warning bcz if any of the above condition not satisfied then what it will return so we should return an any value at the ending or in else block.

Answer (score 1):

Return nil; worked for me.

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

{

```
if(tableViewObj == tableView) //here u can make decision
{

UIView *footerView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x,self.view.frame.origin.y, 320, 40)];

    UIButton *addcharity=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

    [addcharity setTitle:@"Help" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [addcharity addTarget:self action:@selector(addCharity:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [addcharity setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];


    addcharity.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 130, 30); //set some large width to ur title

    [footerView addSubview:addcharity];

    return footerView;
}

return nil;
```

}

I hope it helps someone...

Answer (score 0):

The compiler takes it like that because there is no return statement in the "main" block.

Try to do this instead, and the warning will be gone:

```
- (CGFloat) tableView: (UITableView *) tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *) indexPath
{
    NSString *lineToFit = [[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath: indexPath] line];
    NSString *actorToFit = [[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath: indexPath] actor];
    CGSize lineSize = [lineToFit sizeWithFont: [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize: 12.0f] constrainedToSize: CGSizeMake(320, 800)];
    CGSize actorSize = [actorToFit sizeWithFont: [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize: 12.0f] constrainedToSize: CGSizeMake(320, 800)];

    if (shouldDisplayExtra) {
        kExtraCellType cellType = [self cellIsGoingToContainExtraView];
        if (cellType != kExtraCellTypeNone) {
            [cellsToContainExtra setValue: [NSNumber numberWithInt: cellType] forKey: lineIDString];
            return lineSize.height + actorSize.height + 200;
        }
    }
        // Return the line height, actor height, plus a buffer.
        return lineSize.height + actorSize.height;
}
```

It will have the behaviour you intended, plus no warnings.

Comment: Mm, I did do that already (as mentioned), but I was curious as to why the compiler couldn't work out that it wouldn't get stuck :)