# Control may reach end of non-void function error if-statement

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I'm getting the error Control may reach end of non-void function on this code:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (changeData.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {
        return self.tweets.count;
    } else if (changeData.selectedSegmentIndex == 1) {
        return self.tweets1.count;
    } else if (changeData.selectedSegmentIndex == 2) {
        return self.tweets2.count;
    }
}
```

Why?

Comment: Because the compiler is not as smart as you!

Comment: you have already got your answers below (and the switch case is a better alternative to your approach) but since this is about an **if-else if** without the last else, i'll simply suggest adding the statement `else { return 0;}` or simply `return 0;` before the last `}`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because when your all `if` condition fails, you are not returning anything from the function.

Also multiple return statement in a function is not a good practice.

Do it like:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    int count = 0;
    if (changeData.selectedSegmentIndex == 0)
    {
        count = self.tweets.count;
    }
    elset if (changeData.selectedSegmentIndex == 1)
    {
        count  = self.tweets1.count;
    }
    else if (changeData.selectedSegmentIndex == 2)
    {
        count  = self.tweets2.count;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: Ok, so what should I return then?

Comment: Additionally it would make sense to add an `NSAssert` assertion, so that in the *development* build an exception is thrown if the index has an unexpected value.

Answer (score 2):

Midhun MP has your answer and better code style. I would strongly advice replacing all those nested else-ifs with a switch-statement as, well you don't really want else-ifs if you can avoid them...

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
       NSInteger count = 0;
       switch (changeData.selectedSegmentIndex) 
            {
           case 0:
               count = self.tweets.count;
               break;
           case 1:
               count = self.tweets1.count;
               break;
           case 2:
               count = self.tweets2.count;
               break;
           default:
               break;
            }
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you think its ok disable it:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSInteger count = 0;
    if (changeData.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {
        count = self.tweets.count;
    } else if (changeData.selectedSegmentIndex == 1) {
        count = self.tweets1.count;
    } else {
        count = self.tweets2.count;
    }
   return count;
}
```

or

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
   {
         NSInteger count = 0;
     if (changeData.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {
        count = self.tweets.count;
     } else if (changeData.selectedSegmentIndex == 1) {
        count = self.tweets1.count;
     } 
     else if (changeData.selectedSegmentIndex == 2){
            count =  self.tweets2.count;
     }
     return count;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

While I agree with most answers that suggest to avoid multiple `return`s in the general, on occasions multiple `return`s is nice and useful.  For instance dispatching on an `enum`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

enum direction { north, east, south, west };

std::string to_string(direction d)
{
  switch (d)
    {
#define CASE(C) case C: return #C
      CASE(north);
      CASE(east);
      CASE(south);
      CASE(west);
#undef CASE
    }
}

int main()
{
  std::cout << to_string(west) << '\n';
}
```

If you compile with GCC, you get (C or C++, it's the same):

```
$ g++-4.9 -Wall foo.cc
foo.cc: In function 'std::string to_string(direction)':
foo.cc:17:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
 }
 ^
```

Clang does not complain.  Which is not so nice, actually, since it also compiles this without warnings:

```
int main()
{
  std::cout << to_string(direction(666)) << '\n';
}
```

which results in:

```
$ clang++-3.5 -Wall foo.cc
$ ./a.out
zsh: illegal hardware instruction  ./a.out
```

So one has to "fight" GCC's warning.  One wrong approach would be to add say

```
default:  abort();
```

to the `switch`.  Sure, it cures the symptom, but now GCC will no longer complain if I add a new `direction`, say `zenith`, but forget to cover it in `to_string`.  So really, *never use a default case when switching on an enum*.

Then you can leave an `abort` *after* the `switch` (which is clumsy to do without using inner `return`s).